# Problem with using analogWrite() in arduino

Tags: arduino, hc-05

I am using Arduino Mega, Dc Motor and Cytron 10A motor driver.
I want to control the speed of the DC motor. I am using HC-05 to control the robot.
Here is my code:

```
Arduino:
#define AN1 12
#define AN2 9
#define IN1 13
#define IN2 11
char inChar;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(115200);
pinMode(AN1,OUTPUT);
pinMode(AN2,OUTPUT);
pinMode(IN1,OUTPUT);
pinMode(IN2,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
  inChar = Serial.read();
  Serial.println(inChar);
  }


if (inChar =='F')
{
  analogWrite(AN1,100);
//  analogWrite(AN2,100);
  digitalWrite(IN1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN2,HIGH);
}
if (inChar =='S')
{
  analogWrite(AN1,0);
  analogWrite(AN2,0);
  digitalWrite(IN1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN2,HIGH);
}
}
```

Each motor is able to control speed when connected individually or commenting either analogWrite(AN1,100) or analogWrite(AN2,100). When both are present in code, code doesn't work. Is the problem due to higher baud rate?

However, my code works perfectly on using digitalWrite instead of analogWrite.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also asked at: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=659614

Comment: Yes, I asked there as well

Comment: This might be a hardware/wireing issue. How did you connect the controller to the arduino? Each motor would require 3 outputs for two-way speed controlling, plus one for standby.

Comment: Just curious, if you swap the definition of pin9 with pin 11, will it works?

Comment: @hcheung, I tried, its not working